# determine last background pid from within c++ app

Tags: c, linux, background, arm, pid

I have an embedded linux project I am building in C++. The arch is arm and the processor is a freescale imx6.

I am running multiple audio files in the background using:
sprintf(sysdev,"gst-launch playbin2 uri=file://%s audio-sink=""alsasink device=ossmix"" &",filename);
then executing by: system(sysdev) 
I have also tried using an execvp as well.

After I read the result of: $!

This all works well in a console, but within the c++ program, $! is not returning a result. I actually use: echo $! &> result.dat to pipe the results into a file that is read within the program. The problem is that within the program, the result.dat never gets data... and it pretty obvious that's because $! isnt returning anything.

My guess it that is has something to do with environments.

First, is my approach feasible?

I am pretty new to Linux but my understanding is that I cant 'issue' a PID to a program I run so my only choice is to figure out the ones I've been given as they happen.

Just scanning the results of ps wouldnt be enough because there is the possibility I may have 2 of the same sound running twice.

Thanks in advance for all the brainpower.
Chris

update:
I got it working. I used fork() and in the child it simply called execlp().
In the parent, I logged PID of child.
Finally, I created a thread that monitored the state of all forks using waitforpid(WNOHANG) to keep info updated.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); it has a good chapter about processes.

Answer (score 1):

`$!` is only going to work when the same shell launches the program as the one in which you subsequently evaluate `$!`. Each use of `system` invokes its own shell. From the manual page:

> `system()` executes a command specified in command by calling `/bin/sh -c command`, and returns after the command has been completed.

You are using the wrong approach here. Instead, learn to use `fork()` and one of the functions from the `exec` family, plus a `wait`. The `fork()` will give you the correct pid.

Comment: Ok, but since I am both calling the original sound player and the $! from within my program, wouldnt that be considered the same shell?         Regarding the fork(), I have been a little apprehensive to use it since it makes a complete memory copy of my program, that seems like it would be extremely taxing, especially running multiple forks and on my embedded system. Am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Each use of `system` invokes its own shell. Will amend the question with more info.

Comment: And of course `system` do a `fork` and `execve` of `/bin/sh`

Comment: Indeed, but the PID that `fork` returns is lost in the implementation of `system`.

Comment: So Im researching the fork suggestions and I have a few questions. My intention would be that whatever methods executes the PLAY in the fork (suggested to be exec() vs system()) should immediately return and give my its PID. As I am looking deeper, I see exec() under normal circumstances doesnt return. How can I wait on the process if it never returns. I immediately need access to the PID of the created process.

Comment: `exec` if it works never returns. `fork` however returns twice (once for each PID). In the parent process it will return the PID (assuming it works). In the child, it will return 0, but the child will `exec()`, so that's not really relevant.

Comment: I think Im having an issue wrapping my head around the concept of fork(). First, why would I want another entire copy of my program running? It seems highly inefficient...which leads me to believe I am interpretting this wrong.  I imagine that I may have a 1M+ program running, so why would I want to duplicate the whole thing to run one line of code?  Also, does every single piece of 'parent' code after the fork have to be in the if(!child) context?  The fork() if running the execv never returns so does it just sit in memory wasting a PID? <br>